# How can i start a game/program with the Nvidia gpu in the right click menu?

Tags: scripts, nvidia-optimus

I wanted to create  a script so i  can start a game/program with the Nvidia gpu.

So that when i right-click, i get a option in the menu "Run with Nvidia card"
(Note: i am using [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee))

I tried various things, but until now i dont have succes.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this to happen in nautilus the easiest way seems to be [nautilus-actions](http://www.getdeb.net/software/Nautilus%20Actions).

The alternative is creating a nautilus extension in either C or Python (with [nautilus-python](http://projects.gnome.org/nautilus-python/)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into it as soon as i get behind my laptop... ;)

Comment: mmm... I think i need a bit of help for this one... I will search for that later...

Answer (score 0):

Just some FYI.I believe i read it somewhere in the bumblebee wiki that states you can make a program open in optimus by default by editing something like ***.deskop or something similar..i forget but im 100% percent sure..

Comment: I know that i can edit a *.desktop file to add optirun* but i would love to see it this way.. ;3